# Why is it "get" in "I wish he'd get a haircut"? What tense is "get"?

Tags: conditional-constructions, past-perfect

I don't feel comfortable with the sentence "I wish he'd get a haircut."

I'd like to know the difference in the sentences below and whether or not they are correct:

> - I wish he got a haircut
> - I wish he'd a haircut
> - I wish he'd got a haircut

I don't get why after "had" we are using "get" and not "got"

Comment: In "I wish he'd get" the *'d* is for *would,* not *had*.

Comment: I wish is followed by the conditional tense: would get, would go, would see. Etc.

Answer (score 1):

*He'd* is a contraction of either *he had* or *he would*, depending on context:

> "I wish *he'd* get a haircut" is a contraction of "I wish he would get a haircut" (future tense)
>
> "I wish *he'd* never said that" is a contraction of "I wish he had never said that" (past tense)

With that interpretation, none of your alternate sentences mean the same thing:

1. *I wish he got a haircut*: This sentence is a little ambiguous as to tense: if you want past, I might say something like "I wish *he had gotten* a haircut while he was out near the barber shop"?
2. *I wish he'd a haircut*: People would hear this as "I wish he would a haircut", which doesn't make sense.
3. *I wish he'd got a haircut*: See #1, this would be correct as "I wish he'd gotten a haircut" (past tense).

Comment: *Gotten* has fallen out of use everywhere except North America, so in British English *I wish he had got a haircut* would be expected.

Answer (score -1):

- I wish he got a haircut
- I wish he'd a haircut **<--- This is incorrect**
- I wish he'd got a haircut  **<--- This is incorrect**

You can replace *'d* with *would*

and *get* with *have*

Comment: British English uses *had got* where AmE uses *had gotten* (and consequently *had got* is not incorrect). Where AmE might say "I wish he got" that would not be used (and has no equivalent) in BrE.